# Android TimePicker won't return data

Tags: android, timepicker

I am very new to Android and learning at the moment.

I am trying to implement `TimePicker`. Everything works fine up to the point where the user has to select time and then that particular time does not get updated.

What am I doing wrong? The [rest of my code](https://github.com/Stefanm89/MyCriminalIntent/tree/0ab3a5b9c90cc9cfe9229ebfb291d1ec54ecc25d) can be found on GitHub.

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
  private static final String ARG_TIME = "date";
  public static final String EXTRA_TIME = "time";
  private TimePicker mTimePicker;

  public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_TIME, date);

    TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }


  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.picker_time_fragment, null);
    final Date time = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_TIME);

    Calendar a = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int hour = a.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int minute = a.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mTimePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.time_picker_layout);


    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setView(v)
        .setTitle(R.string.time_picker_crime_title)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
              mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
              mTimePicker.setMinute(minute);
            }

            sendResultTime(Activity.RESULT_OK, time);
          }
        })
        .show();
  }

  private void sendResultTime(int resultCode, Date time) {
    if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
      return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time);

    getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
  }

}
```

Comment: why you are using sdk version check condition equal or above marshmallow?

Comment: Otherwise is says Call requires API level 23 (current min is 16). And I can't use .setCurrentHour. What should I do?

Comment: is it working in marshmallow devices ?

Comment: Try using `mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
              mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);` and remove that sdk condition

Answer (score 0):

```
String deli_time = shared_preference.getString("delivery_time", "");
List<String> timeList1 = Arrays.asList(deli_time.split(" ")); 
String time_value = timeList1.get(1).trim()+" "+timeList1.get(2).trim();
Date dateObj = sdf2.parse(time_value);
time_value = sdf1.format(dateObj);
Date dateObj1 = sdf3.parse(timeList1.get(0));
dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(dateObj1);
String time = "";
time = ZainbowDatabase.getInstance(MyBasket.this).getTimeForDay(mall_id, t1_vendor_id, dayOfTheWeek, 2);

if(time.length() > 0 && !time.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
    String time1, time2 = "";
    if(time.contains(",")){
        List<String> timeList = Arrays.asList(time.split(","));
        time1 = timeList.get(0);
        time2 = timeList.get(1);
    }else
        time1 = time;

    boolean check_time = AppConstant.checkTime(time1, time2, time_value);
```

Relate to this code for timePicker. This might help . Ignore the Zainbow DB line. This is just verifying the time for a particular entity. No need of that whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
 mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);`

Instead of this:

`mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
 mTimePicker.setMinute(minute);`

and remove that sdk condition...

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, but when I use mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hour) it says that it is deprecated and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the TimePickerDialog? Im sure you just want the user to select a time of day right? Here is what you need:

```
TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
              @Override
              public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                //User selected something           
              }
        }, 9, 11, true);
timePicker.show();
```